# Connection reset in long session

Tags: java, hibernate, threadpool

I have a standalone Thread application. Which is a listener waiting for a message, and when it arrives do somethings, in which I have to save in the DB the message. 
But I have problems because if I run the application and "send manually a message" everythings works fine, but if I run the application and wait for a message of the system (for instance one hour after it arrives) when the APP 's going to save to the DB it sinks, telling:

java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection reset
or
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Io Exception: Connection reset

I'm using Hibernate 3.2.6 with C3p0 0.9.2.1

The configuration of the session is:

```
public final class PersistenceUtil{
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            String location = ServiceLocator.getInstance().getConfigurationService().getProperty("adaptor.location");
            if (LOC_1.equals(location)) {
                sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.1.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
            } else if(LOC_2.equals(location)) {
                sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.2.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
            }else {
                sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            }
            sessionFactory.openSession();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }


    private PersistenceUtil() {
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        try {
            sessionFactory.close();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            LOG.error("PersistanceUtil.shutdown Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

When I want to save I do (and where is the error):

```
public T save(T entity) {

        if (!getSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
            log.warn("Session not active. Starting the session");
            getSession().beginTransaction();
        }

        getSession().save(entity);
        getSession().getTransaction().commit();
        return entity;
    }
```

And my hibernate.cfg.xml is:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">URL</property>
        <property name="connection.username">USER</property>
        <property name="connection.password">Password</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">0</property>

        <mapping class="MessageEO" />
        <mapping class="CustomerEO" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create new session before attempting to save your data? According to Hibernate's docs this is proper approach for atomic operation. As I can see your comments in code, you think that starting transaction means starting new session or opening new connection whitch is not true. You can have multiple (but not always nested) transactions per session.
I always use following template for atomic operation - it never let me down. I even have this piece of code as template in Eclipse:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        // save/ update / delete your entities here
        tx.commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

Principles:

1. Hold single `SessionFactory` object. Creating it is expensive.
2. For every bulk of operation (saving, modifing etc.) or single entities open new session using factory - it is lightweight and thread safe.
3. Sessions itself are not thread safe.
4. Always start new transactions and roll commit/rollback them if needed. Even for read-only data fetches.
5. Always close your session after your bulk operations are done (releasing connections etc.)
6. Never use same same session in whitch exception has had occured.

Comment: I don't do because this code it's an inherit code from other person. And I'm going crazy in the long time testing. I going to do as you said. When a message arrives open the connection, begin the transaction and do the batch operations on the DB and before end the process of the message commit and close the session. Thanks

Comment: open session - not connection. Yep, that should fix your problem. Be aware that as I can see you are opening session in your `PersistanceUtils`. Thats probably because of automating session per thread management. I am not experienced in using it, but I prefer to do it myself - better control = better code maintenance.